# Why is the electrolytic capacitor not polarity sensitive?

Tags: microphone, electrolytic-capacitor, polarity

### The issue

I was making a project in which I had to use a 2.2uF electrolytic capacitor in series with a microphone and weirdly, the circuit works even if I toggle the polarity of the capacitor, that is **the capacitor can be inserted in either polarity** to make the circuit work.
Why does this happen? What are the criteria for doing so intentionally? Additionally, if I am to substitute a ceramic capacitor with an electrolytic capacitor, in what polarity should the capacitor be inserted?

#### Schematic:

[image: Bluetooth Audio Adapter]

> This schematic is based on the manufacturer's schematic, in which also, a **ceramic capacitor** of 2.2uF is used.

This question is referring to the MIC portion of the schematic only.

Comment: What was the original capacitor type? Also, there is no DC bias in that part of the circuit.

Comment: That is likely a ceramic capacitor. Unless noted otherwise you can assume all aluminum and tantalum capacitors ARE polarized. If you install them backwards across power supply rails (or they have an internal short, much less common in recent decades) they tend to go BANG with some violence, possibly charring the PCB. A ceramic capacitor is not polarized unless it has a black band or polarity mark at one end.

Comment: At millivolt level and and a small reverse bias a polarized capacitor doesn't care, at least for a short time. Over time it might die much earlier than you expect. Don't try it again.

Comment: @Toor What do you mean by the original capacitor type?

Comment: @Sparky256 Yes, the manufacturer recommends ceramic capacitor, but I don't have such a high valued ceramic capacitor so I used an electrolytic capacitor. As above comment states(and I checked voltage levels) there is no DC bias in that portion of the circuit. Does it imply that I can't use a polarized capacitor in such case?

Comment: @Ale..chenski What stable alternative should I go for?

Comment: What is the voltage on pin5 (R2)? There should be some bias. But for "stable alternative" you should go for a ceramic capacitor.

Comment: @Ale..chenski The pinout states that pin5 is MIC- and pin4 is MIC+. I tested it myself and there was and pin4 was indeed higher by 0.1V(which I had wrongly ignored).

Comment: Also, is it a good idea to use an electrolytic capacitor instead of ceramic capacitor considering there is sufficient DC bias?

Comment: You only mention the capacitor that you first used was 2.2uF and that it worked in both polarities. However, you never mentioned what type of capacitor it actually was. 2.2uF makes it likely that it was a bipolar type and if it was, of course it would have worked in both directions.

Comment: @Toor Oh, sorry for not mentioning that. The capacitor isn't bipolar. It is a commonly used 2.2uF polarized electrolytic capacitor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An aluminum electrolytic will handle a reverse polarity of about 1 volt or so.  The cap probably never sees anything near that.

This [appnote](http://www.nichicon.co.jp/english/products/pdf/aluminum.pdf) from Nichicon shows that under 1V the capacitors don't have much of leakage and seems fully functional, see Fig.2-2, with little degradation (see Fig.2-3).

Comment: Would you suggest its use in a circuit meant to be used for long terms?

Comment: @UtkarshVerma, please read the Nichicon article and make your own determination. The article mentions "  progressing  formation  of  an  oxide layer  on  the  cathode  electrode", so the cap might not last longer than 200-300 hours.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Thanks for the document. I'll read it and post what I'll conclude over here.

Comment: It depends on the voltage rating. At one time we safely used -10%